# ncurses: Subwin or subpad of a pad

Tags: c, ncurses

Assume there is a ncurses pad.

1.) Can I create a *subwin* of the pad?
Theoretically, the subwin would share memory with the pad. But what would happen when I call `wrefresh` on this subwindow?

2.) Can I create a *subpad* of the pad? If yes, does it make sense to call `wrefresh` or `prefresh` on the subpad?

My current understanding is that one must create a subpad for a pad. The coordinates that are passed to the `subpad` function specifiy the location w.r.t. the (parent) pad. The returned subpad is conceptually a window (cannot be larger than its parent structure), although it must be put to the screen with the `prefresh` function. It shares memory with the parent pad. Correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pads are not regular windows; you cannot make a window inside a pad.

The ncurses library makes these checks, which relate to the question:

- in [`subpad`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-subwin), it checks to ensure that the parent is a *pad*, and then calls [`derwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-derwin) to do the rest of the work.  If the parent is not a *pad*, `subpad` returns an error.
- `subwin` uses `derwin`, which ensures that if the parent is a *pad*, then the result is a pad.  Either way, the result is the same type as the parent.

A pad does not exactly "share" memory with a window; it is just a convenient way to translate coordinates to a window.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, I get the same result for calling `subwin`and `subpad` on a pad, because both functions eventually call `derwin`. The returned thing is always a pad, which must be refreshed with `prefresh`. Correct?